# Decorators for authentication using oauth in Django

Tags: python, django, oauth, python-decorators

I am trying to complete Oauth1 using a Decorator in Django. Until before I tried using decorator, I was doing it using this endpoint `oauth` (which works alright):

Note: `OSCAR_CALLBACK_URL` is URL for `oauth` endpoint only

```
def oauth(request):
    if not request.GET.get('oauth_verifier'):
        return oscar_oauth_init(request)
    else:
        res = oscar_oauth_accesstoken(request)
        return res

def oscar_oauth_init(request):
    oauth = OAuth1(OSCAR_CLIENT_ID, client_secret=OSCAR_CLIENT_SECRET)
    url=OSCAR_INIT_URL+OSCAR_CALLBACK_URL
    r = requests.get(url=url, auth=oauth)
    credentials = convert(parse_qs(r.content))
    resource_owner_key = str(credentials.get('oauth_token')[0])
    resource_owner_secret = str(credentials.get('oauth_token_secret')[0])
    verifier = oscar_oauth_auth(resource_owner_key)
    request.session['resource_owner_key'] = str(resource_owner_key)
    request.session['resource_owner_secret'] = str(resource_owner_secret)
    request.session['verifier'] = str(verifier)
    return verifier


def oscar_oauth_accesstoken(request):
    verifier = request.GET.get('oauth_verifier')
    resource_owner_key = request.GET.get('oauth_token')
    resource_owner_secret = request.session.get('resource_owner_secret')
    oauth = OAuth1(OSCAR_CLIENT_ID,
                   client_secret=OSCAR_CLIENT_SECRET,
                   resource_owner_key=resource_owner_key,
                   resource_owner_secret=resource_owner_secret,
                   verifier=verifier)

    r = requests.get(url=OSCAR_TOKEN_URL+verifier, auth=oauth)
    credentials = convert(parse_qs(r.content))
    resource_owner_key = credentials.get('oauth_token')[0]
    resource_owner_secret = credentials.get('oauth_token_secret')[0]
    request.session['resource_owner_key'] = str(resource_owner_key)
    request.session['resource_owner_secret'] = str(resource_owner_secret)
    return credentials
```

This endpoint was required to be called before other API calls that needed user to be authorized.

I am trying to refactor this using the following decorator now:

```
def oscar_login(view_func):
    def _wrapped_view_func(request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.GET.get('oauth_verifier'):
            return oscar_oauth_init(request)
        else:
            return oscar_oauth_accesstoken(request)
        return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
    return _wrapped_view_func
```

I am not sure how to complete the redirection bit using the decorator. I allowed redirection to the same endpoint `oauth` (shared above) but the flow stops at end of the endpoint that I allowed redirection to and does not continue with the API call that was to be made after it was through the decorator. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Why are you using something with name `OAuth1`? You mentioned that you want OAuth2

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? It doesn't look like proper OAuth2 for me.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh: That was a typo. I meant to say Oauth1 only.  I am using Oauth1

Comment: You absolutely shouldn't use OAuth1 in 2020. OAuth1 is deprecated because of security reasons.

Comment: @VladimirSerykh External module that provides authentication using Oauth1

Answer (score 2):

Normally in Django the decorator and the authentication would be separate:

- The decorator would probably be one of the built-in ones, such as [`@login_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-login-required-decorator) or [`@permission_required`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/default/#the-permission-required-decorator).
- The authentication would be configured using an [authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing), probably an off-the-shelf one (a quick google suggests [django-oauth-toolkit](https://django-oauth-toolkit.readthedocs.io) as a possibility).

This de-couples the application logic from the authentication method, making each piece easier to develop, update and manage.